# Divide a color wheel into segments of solid colors

Tags: python, colors, rgb, hsv

Given the following Python code, it is possible to derive a color distribution that evenly spreads hues radially:

```py
from PIL import Image
import colorsys
import math
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":      

    im = Image.new("RGB", (250,250))
    cx, cy = im.size[0]/2, im.size[1]/2
    pix = im.load()

    for x in range(im.width):
        for y in range(im.height):
            rx = x - cx
            ry = y - cy

            h = ((math.atan2(ry, rx) / math.pi) + 1.0) / 2.0
            rgb = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(h, 1.0, 1.0)
            pix[x,y] = tuple([int(round(c*255.0)) for c in rgb])
    im.show()
```

**Output:**

[image: ![![radial color distribution]

I'd like to be able to enforce segments of evenly distributed hues based on a **variable number** of segments/colors. For example, given a chosen number of 12 segments/colors would result in the following distribution:

[image: ![segmented radial color distribution]

How could I go about achieving this?

Comment: What are you hoping for as the answer please? If you divide 360 degrees by 12 segments, they'll each subtend 30 degrees at the centre.

Comment: That's correct. The number of segments would preferably be an adjustable variable.